# Problems rephrased as quadratic unconstrained binary optimization

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, optimization, counting-complexity

I was impressed when i came across [Quadratic unconstrained binary optimization (QUBO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_unconstrained_binary_optimization) recently, and saw how one can rephrase many combinatorial problems into questions about optima of binary functions. A very nice review with many examples can be found in Andrew Lucas' [Ising formulations of many NP problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5843). He shows problems such as [Graph Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) or [3SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) as a minimisation problem.

My question is: In general, what type of problems can be mapped to QUBO? In particular, is it possible to map even more difficult problem (such as counting solutions of 3SAT or other [#P problems](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P)) to QUBO?

Are there examples for that, or would that contradict some results or strongly believed conjectures about [computation complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity)?

Comment: Is QUBO not in NP, and thus NP-Complete? If it is, your question is equivalent to some flavor of $\#P \subseteq NP$, which is famously still open.